# Создание почтового ящика Exchange с помощью delphi

Tags: delphi, email, exchange, delphi-10.3-rio

Есть программа для создания/редактирования доменных пользователей. Необходимо создать почту Exchange для пользователя. Всё сделал, но вот с `Exchange` не работал,каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: Вопрос, собственно, состоит из двух: 1) Какой api предоставляет exchange для создания почты? 2) Как этот api правильно вызывать из Delphi? Вы знаете ответ хоть на один из них?

Comment: В этом и вся проблема. Я вообще не имею понятия как и с чем "есть" exchange.

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с Exchange 2013 единственный способ создания почтового ящика - [вызов команды New-Mailbox из PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/New-Mailbox?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=exchange-ps)

Вот аналогичный вопрос на англоязычной версии сайта https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25378911/how-to-create-new-mail-account-microsoft-exchange-2013-ews